# InputField equations and Solve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, dynamic

I'm trying to get this piece of code to work:

```
Panel[
 DynamicModule[{f = x, g = -x},
  xmax = 10;
  Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[f], ContinuousAction -> True], 
   InputField[Dynamic[g]], 
   Dynamic[ Show[Plot[{f, g}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, AspectRatio -> 1,
                              PlotRange -> {{-xmax, xmax}, {-xmax, xmax}}]
                ]
          ]
        }]
              ]
     ]
```

This works and updates dynamically the graphs of `f` and `g`. Now, I would like to add the intersections, dynamically, if any (so with a `IF` testing), and I tried different things, without success:

```
solution = Dynamic[Solve[f == g, {x,y}]
```

gives me indeed the dynamically updated solution. But I can't use this information to plot points, nor even get `Length[solution]` update dynamically...

Any help with this?

Comment: [This is the static version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28987/5478) of your question. Take a look there. `solution` definition looks strange, use `solution:=...` and use `Dynamic` at the end in the plotting procedure. p.s. isn't `Show` redundant?

Comment: Thank you for this static version, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is only for simple cases where the intersection is a point. And not adapted for cases with periodical functions when the output of the `Solve` contains a conditional expression (sometimes).

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{f = x, g = -x, xmax = 20},

  Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[f], ContinuousAction -> True],
    InputField[Dynamic[g]],
    Dynamic @ Plot[{f, g}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> xmax, 
                                             Epilog -> {PointSize@.02, Point[pt]}]
        }]
  , Initialization :> (pt := ({x, f} /. NSolve[f == g, x, Reals]) /. {x, f} -> {})
      ]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer a lot, thank you very much. One question though, what do you mean by
"/. {x, f} -> {}" ?
Would this be equivalent to

{x, f} /. NSolve[f == g, x, Reals])[[1]]
?
Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel when there is no solution there is no replacement rules so in this case `{x,f}` is switching to `{}` because it will not cause any error in `Epilog`. I'm glad it is helpful.