# Need help in solving a trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve the following equation?

```
w^2 -(2*w^2*Sin[w] + w^2*Sin[w] + w^3 + w^3*Cot[w]*Sin[w])/
  (Sin[w]+2*Cot[w]*(Sin[w])^2 - 2*w - 2*w*Cot[w]*Sin[w]) = 0
```

Comment: Have you at least tried simplifying your equation first?

Comment: Note that you also want `==` ([`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) rather than `=` ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)).  I hope you've searched the docs and found `Solve`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution)

Answer (score 4):

To make it a bit easier for typing purposes, let's define a function of `w` for your expression.

```
f[w_] := w^2 - (2*w^2*Sin[w] + w^2*Sin[w] + w^3 + 
     w^3*Cot[w]*Sin[w])/(Sin[w] + 2*Cot[w]*(Sin[w])^2 - 2*w - 
     2*w*Cot[w]*Sin[w])
```

Plot the function to get an idea of where the zeros occur.

```
Plot[f[w], {w, -6 π, 6 π}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that it appears to be zero at `w=0`. However you need to take a limit because the expression is zero/zero.

```
Limit[f[w], w -> 0]
(* 0 *)
```

One can use `Solve` or `Reduce` to give an answer over a certain range.

```
sol = Solve[{f[w] == 0, -2 π < w < 2 π}, w]
(* {{w -> 
   Root[{2 Sin[#1] - 2 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] + 3 #1 + 
       3 Cos[#1] #1 &, -3.7631414554458760041}]}, {w -> 
   Root[{2 Sin[#1] - 2 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] + 3 #1 + 3 Cos[#1] #1 &, 
     3.7631414554458760041}]}} *)
```

Those strange looking `Root` expressions can be numerically evaluated as follows.

First we use `Part` to extract the expressions and subsequently apply `N` to get the numerical value.

```
sol[[1, 1, 2]] // N
(* -3.76314 *)

sol[[2, 1, 2]] // N
(* 3.76314 *)
```

`Reduce` gives a similar result. `Reduce` typically is more robust than `Solve` for challenging cases.

```
Reduce[{f[w] == 0, -2 π < w < 2 π}, w]
(* w == 
  Root[{2 Sin[#1] - 2 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] + 3 #1 + 
      3 Cos[#1] #1 &, -3.7631414554458760041}] || 
 w == Root[{2 Sin[#1] - 2 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] + 3 #1 + 3 Cos[#1] #1 &, 
    3.7631414554458760041}] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
f[w_] = w^2 - (2*w^2*Sin[w] + w^2*Sin[w] + w^3 + w^3*Cot[w]*Sin[w])/
     (Sin[w] + 2*Cot[w]*(Sin[w])^2 - 2*w - 2*w*Cot[w]*Sin[w]) //
   Together // FullSimplify

(* (w^2*(3*w*Cos[w/2] + 4*Sin[w/2]^3))/(2*w*Cos[w/2] - Sin[(3*w)/2]) *)

f[w] == f[-w] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The function is even so it is only necessary to find the nonnegative roots to know all of the roots.

The function oscillates so the number of solutions depends on the range of interest.

```
(soln = NSolve[{f[w] == 0, 0 <= w < 20}, w, WorkingPrecision -> 25]) // 
   Column
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions

```
f[w] /. soln // Chop[#, 10^-20] &

(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

{Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The solution at `w == 0` is a limiting case

```
Limit[f[w], w -> 0]

(* 0 *)

Plot[f[w], {w, 0, 16.5}, PlotRange -> {-20, 20},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{w, 0} /. soln]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be extract the coordinates of the intersection points directly from the plot (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

First, I have simplified the equation (following the suggestion from @J.M.):

```
w^2 - (2*w^2*Sin[w] + w^2*Sin[w] + w^3 + w^3*Cot[w]*Sin[w])/(Sin[w] + 
  2*Cot[w]*(Sin[w])^2 - 2*w - 2*w*Cot[w]*Sin[w]) ==  0 // FullSimplify

(* w^2 (1 + (w + w Cos[w] + 3 Sin[w])/(2 w (1 + Cos[w]) - (1 + 2 Cos[w]) Sin[w])) == 0 *)
```

So one solution is $w=0$, though this is clear from the original equation.

Now the second condition is:

```
(w + w Cos[w] + 3 Sin[w])/(2 w (1 + Cos[w]) - (1 + 2 Cos[w])Sin[w]))==-1
```

and it will gives more solutions.

Plotting both terms:

[image]

and only their intersections:

```
zeros = Plot[{(w + w Cos[w] + 3 Sin[w])/(2 w (1 + Cos[w]) - (1 + 2 Cos[w])Sin[w]), -1}, {w, -8 \[Pi], 8 \[Pi]}, 
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{w, f}, 
 1 + (w + w Cos[w] + 3 Sin[w])/(2 w (1 + Cos[w]) - (1 + 2 Cos[w]) Sin[w])]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]]]
```

[image]

Finally we extract the coordinates of this points (it seems that the function is *undocumented* as I could not get any information from MMA reference):

```
intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[zeros]

(* {{-22.1116, -1.}, {-15.8751, -1.}, {-9.69343, -1.}, {-3.76328, -1.},
   {3.76327, -1.}, {9.6937, -1.}, {15.8744, -1.},{22.1116, -1.}} *)
```

If you want more roots, just move the `PlotRange`. This is so because if you expand the x-axis, the plot could not have enough resolution to obtain all the intersections.