# How do I know the calculation time of an equation solving?

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation

```
Solve[ Sqrt[Abs[x]^2+Abs[-5+y]^2]+Sqrt[Abs[-5+x]^2+Abs[y]^2]
      +Sqrt[Abs[5+x]^2+Abs[y]^2]+Sqrt[Abs[x]^2+Abs[5+y]^2]==24 &&
      -6 < x < 6, y]
```

When I evaluated this expression, after almost 30 minutes I've got nothing.
I am not sure whether that's because my *Intel i7 CPU*, I guess it's strong enough.

How can I solve this equation?

How can I know the calculation time? I'd quit if needed more than 1 hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you can't know in advance how long you should wait for solutions (even you won't know if the system is capable to provide them at all). There is `TimeConstrained[expr, constr]` to stop computation of `expr` when it exceeds the time constraint `constr`.

Nonetheless `Solve` works fine (`Reduce` even finer, this is a huge issue, see e.g. this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)) and it is capable to provide solutions quickly if you supplement the system to be solved with appropriate restriction on variables. To realize what kind of  restrictions you should add to solvers I'd recommend to examine thoroughly this post [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952)  Having used `ContourPlot` you should easily figure out them. So we can get solutions

```
sols = y /. 
Solve[ Sqrt[ Abs[x]^2 + Abs[-5 + y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[-5 + x]^2 + Abs[y]^2] + 
     Sqrt[Abs[5 + x]^2 + Abs[y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[5 + y]^2] == 24 &&
    -6 < x < 6 && -6 < y < 6, y];
```

Solutions are represented in terms of the `Root` objects, sometimes they can be rewritten in terms of radicals (see e.g. this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768))

Now, we can plot the solutions:

```
Plot[ sols, {x, -2 Sqrt[6], 2 Sqrt[6]}, 
      AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

To realize what you might expect if you assume that `y` is complex, it is advantageous to exploit `ContourPlot`.   I write `y` as `z == k I + y`, that is `y` is the real part of `z`, e.g. :

```
With[{k = 1.316}, 
  ContourPlot[ Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[-5 + k I + y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[-5 + x]^2 + Abs[k I + y]^2]
              + Sqrt[Abs[5 + x]^2 + Abs[k I + y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[x]^2
              + Abs[5 + k I + y]^2] == 24,
              {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6},
              AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

To get a bit deeper insight we'll look at the animation.

```
soly = 
  Table[ ContourPlot[ Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[-5 + k I + y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[-5 + x]^2 
                      + Abs[k I + y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[5 + x]^2 + Abs[k I + y]^2] 
                      + Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[5 + k I + y]^2] == 24,
                     {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
          PlotLegends -> Placed[ Style[Row[{"k =", NumberForm[k, {4, 2}]}], Bold, 20],
                                {Left, Top}], ContourStyle -> Thick],
         {k, -3.316, 3.316, 0.04}];

ListAnimate[ soly, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Having looked at the `ContourPlot` the exact bounds can be found from `Solve[Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[-5 + y]^2] + 
      Sqrt[Abs[-5 + x]^2 + Abs[y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[5 + x]^2 + Abs[y]^2] +
       Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[5 + y]^2] == 
     24 /. #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{y -> 0, x}, {x -> 0, y}}`

Answer (score 3):

`y` is a real number, right? Then

```
eqn = Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[-5 + y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[-5 + x]^2 + Abs[y]^2] + 
     Sqrt[Abs[5 + x]^2 + Abs[y]^2] + Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[5 + y]^2] == 24 && -6 < x < 6;

(* Solution 1 *)
sol = Solve[eqn /. Abs -> RealAbs, y]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.37403, Null} *)
(* Solution 2 *)
sol2 = Solve[eqn, y, Reals]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.44141, Null} *)
```

Comment: `y` should be expression, not a number

Comment: @kittygirl A preciser statement is "`y` is an expression that evaluates to a real number for any desirable `x`" of course.

Comment: +1 for bringing up `RealAbs`. I didn't know that and I was positively surprised that `RealAbs'` evaluates to somethin reasonable (although I am a bit disappointed by `RealAbs'').